# Вызов WebAssembly из JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c++, fetch, webassembly

У меня есть программа C++ на 1000+ строк. Программа состоит из одной функции, которая принимает на вход пять unsigned int (или 1 unsigned char и 4 unsigned int), возвращая либо строку, либо 4 unsigned int (я не совсем понимаю, как вернуть массив чисел, поэтому использую строку). При этом сама функция вызывает другие функции программы в процессе вычисления.
Я скомпилировал программу с помощью WasmExplorer в wasm файл.

Как вызвать функцию получившегося wasm файла из javascript, получив результат?
Пример типа:

```js
let squarer;

function loadWebAssembly(fileName) {
  return fetch(fileName)
    .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
    .then(bits => WebAssembly.compile(bits))
    .then(module => { return new WebAssembly.Instance(module) });
};

loadWebAssembly('http://test.ru/squarer.wasm')
  .then(instance => {
    squarer = instance.exports._Z7squareri;
    console.log('Finished compiling! Ready when you are...');
  });
```

Выдаёт 7 ошибок

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
```

И 1 ошибку

```
Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: WebAssembly.Instance is disallowed on the main thread, if the buffer size is larger than 4KB. Use WebAssembly.instantiate.
```

на строку

```
then(module => { return new WebAssembly.Instance(module) });
```

Comment: а вы пробовали просто перевести ошибку? вот во второй строке даже говорится, что нужно сделать

Comment: а первая скорее всего результат второй, у вас модуль очень большой

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45285081/5703133